# Stack Overflow URLs in double quotes in answers are not replaced by the name of the question

Tags: bug, status-review, answers, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

Whilst quoting a super useful answer in [a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079097/16633550), I enclosed the URL in double-quotes `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070115/why-is-the-middleware-not-processed-on-404-page-in-django"`, which rendered in the preview as `"Why is the Middleware not processed on 404 page in Django?"` as a link to the page. Wonderful.

However, on posting the question, the link is rendered as `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070115/why-is-the-middleware-not-processed-on-404-page-in-django"` which is less wonderful. So I had to put spaces inside the double quotes to make it into the name of the URL.

Preview and posting should agree with each other; and I'd prefer if previews behaviour was replicated in the post, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Re *"I had to put spaces inside the double quotes"*: Or, as for external links, use the normal way of linking, not relying on the auto convert.

Comment: FWIW, if you think another Q&A answers a question then *vote/flag as duplicate*. Don't add an answer only to refer to what another answer already says better.

Comment: Leaving aside duplicates: I can't actually think of a reason to put the link to a question in quotes. Stylistically, it's *a link*, it's already distinct element of the text. There is no reason to separate it. Unlike a title of a book, for example, where you'd want to put quotes to distinguish it. You're also not *quoting* anything. Just listing where something is - that something being a link. The quotes wouldn't be used to denote *literal meaning*. Nor would sarcastic/scare quotes be applicable. It might be a text processing bug but I don't see valid usage where the bug is a problem.

Comment: @rene I don't think that's a duplicate; that post describes a bug where quotes _in the link_ aren't escaped properly in the preview. This one is concerning quotes interfering with the auto-conversion that occurs for Stack Exchange links in the rendered view.

Comment: @zcoop98 I was hoping that we by now have a canonical for  "preview is different from actual post" bugs. Do we really need every single variation as a separate bug or could we just lump some together so a dev can address all of the same issue at once?

Comment: @rene I'm not necessarily against that for the small ones, but the post you picked isn't that. I feel like we should set up a post that properly explains why this happens if we're gonna close them like that.

Comment: While I seem to recall that there's a duplicate for this, at least on MSE, if not here on MSO, the [duplicate target which was used here](/q/345847/3773011) is likely a different bug. The two show opposite issues wrt. if it's properly rendered in the preview or on the server. This question is about what happens in the SE-specific rendering of SE post/question titles from just a URL, while the previous duplicate target is about straight CommonMark Markdown conversion to HTML. The parsing for those are almost certainly separate, with the URL➞SE post title conversion likely a pre-processing step.

Comment: Answer with an example of this bug: [answer to: "Formatting Sandbox"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380624/271271)